# How does *args works in case of list() function?

Tags: python-3.x

I thought I understand the concept of `*args` until I found the function below (I left only the part I'm interested in):

```
def foo(*args):
    return list(args)

foo(1,2) # [1,2]
```

`list()` function only accepts 1 argument. How is it possible for the `foo` function to work?

Comment: You're only _passing_ one argument to `list`, why wouldn't it work?

Comment: Because it’s part of the Python programming language. It’s called argument unpacking. You can pass a list named `args` and the `foo` method will unpack all items as if they were passed individually.

Comment: @MartinBean I think you have that backwards. [Starargs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) (the actual name for this construct, [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) refers to something else) let you to compact a series of positional arguments into a single tuple. Inside `foo`, `args` is just a plain old tuple. No sequences are being unpacked into multiple arguments here.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `foo`, `args` is tuple with 2 elements (in this case).
It is equivalent to `list((1,2))`